# Error building go compiler from source

Tags: linux, go, build

I am trying to build the latest version (tip of the master branch) of Go from source.

The official Go documentation (https://golang.org/doc/install/source) states that you should download Go 1.4 binaries to build a more recent version. However it should be possible to build all from source.

To do this, I set variables  in `.bashrc` :

```
PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"
export GOPATH=$HOME
```

then to build go 1.4 from source :

```
source ~/.bashrc
git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go
mkdir ~/go1.4
cd ~/go
git archive --format=tar go1.4.3 |tar -xv -C ~/go1.4
cd ~/go1.4/src
./make.bash
```

and finally build the latest version :

```
cd ~/go/src/
GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=$HOME/go1.4 ./make.bash
```

I remember doing this months ago without problems, but today I get these errors building go 1.4 `make.bash`:

```
# cmd/pprof
.../go1.4/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/cgo.a(_all.o): unknown relocation type 42; compiled without -fpic?
.../go1.4/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/cgo.a(_all.o): unknown relocation type 42; compiled without -fpic?
runtime/cgo(.text): unexpected relocation type 298
runtime/cgo(.text): unexpected relocation type 298
...
```

Is there something wrong in my method ?

Comment: 1. Never ever set GOROOT. 2 Build tip like `GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/path/to/go1.6/go/tool ./make.bash`

Comment: Also, don't put go1.4/bin in your PATH.

Comment: @Volker: ok i don't use GOROOT, but GOROOT_BOOSTRAP should point to an existing GO compiler.I updated the question but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages point to CGO, and environment variables that control `make.bash` are explained at the beginning of the file :

> CGO_ENABLED: Controls cgo usage during the build. Set it to 1
>   to include all cgo related files, .c and .go file with "cgo"
>   build directive, in the build. Set it to 0 to ignore them.

so if you disable CGO while building GO 1.4 :

```
cd ~/go1.4/src
CGO_ENABLED=0 ./make.bash
```

everything works and pass the tests.